# Python list and int only works when debugging

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm making a code that when running through is giving me a list `dropd` with just 1 item and a variable `age` that was supposed to be a int continues a string.

When I work with the code in Debug mode I notice that If I execute only the list `dropd` line then It gives me the correct items and if I execute the `age = int(agee)` alone then It gives me an int as result.

What`s going on here?

```
    if sistema_selected == 2:
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@data-id='1']"))
        ...
        time.sleep(3)

        try:
            print('CPF Valido')

            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mudarMatricula"]/div/div/select').click()

            dropd = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/form/
                 div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h3/span[1]/div/div/select/option')


            i = 0
            for item in dropd:
                time.sleep(1)
                item.click()

                ...
                agee = idade_split[idade_split.index('Anos') - 1]
                age = int(agee)
                ...

                if age < 75:
                    idade_plc = Label(frame_idade, text=age, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
                    idade_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
                elif age > 75:
                    idade_plc = Label(frame_idade, text=age, borderwidth=1, relief="groove", bg='red')
                    idade_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
                nome_plc = Label(frame_nome, text=nome)
                nome_plc.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=EW)
                ...

        # IF THE CLIENT CODE IS WRONG
        except (NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
            print('CPF Invalido')
```

Comment: So, is `age` an `int` or not? If not, how do you know?

Comment: `agee` that originates `age` is a string because I'm getting It from a text, but I can also confirme that inside the debug from pycharm. As I need to use that with `> 75` I'm doing `age = int(agee)` to convert it to a int, but if I run the whole code inside Debug It shows me that `age` is still a string, but If i run just `age = int(agee)` to test I get age as a int. The same occurs with dropd, that was supposed to be a list with more than one item.

Comment: So you are saying that when ‘age’ is a string you get an exception from the comparison ‘age < 75’?

Comment: Yes, I get `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int`.` Do you know why when I run just the specific line in Debug I get what was expected?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.